# ListBox with DockPanel Alignment

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, dockpanel

I have a `listbox` in which I pass 5 items in each row.
Xml file:

```xml
<ListBox x:Name="DatabaseBox">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel">
                <Image x:Name="ToggleFavoriteImage" Width="15" Height="15" Tag="{Binding Tag}" Source="{Binding ImageSource}" MouseLeftButtonDown="ToggleFavoriteImage_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="ListBoxSName" Width="220" Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="30,0,0,0" FontSize="11" MouseLeftButtonDown="ListBoxSName_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
                <Button x:Name="ListBoxSCoyntry" Height="17" Content="{Binding City}" FontSize="11" Click="ListBoxSCity_Click"/>
                <Button x:Name="ListBoxSCity"  Height="17" Content="{Binding Genre}" FontSize="11" Click="ListBoxSGenre_Click"/>
                <Button x:Name="ListBoxSGenre" Height="17" Content="{Binding Country}" FontSize="11" Click="ListBoxSCountry_Click"/>
            </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    
</ListBox>
```

What I want to do is have `Image` and `TextBlock` docked Left, and all the others Docked right side by side.
I tried `DockPanel.Dock ="Rigth"` for all the `Buttons` but things get very messed up.

Anyone with an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap each visual group in a stack panel and apply the docking to the stackpanel, like so:

```
<DockPanel>
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left">
         <Image x:Name="ToggleFavoriteImage" Width="15" Height="15" Tag="{Binding Tag}" Source="{Binding ImageSource}" MouseLeftButtonDown="ToggleFavoriteImage_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
         <TextBlock x:Name="ListBoxSName" Width="220" Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="30,0,0,0" FontSize="11" MouseLeftButtonDown="ListBoxSName_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right">
         <Button x:Name="ListBoxSCoyntry" Height="17" Content="{Binding City}" FontSize="11" Click="ListBoxSCity_Click"/>
         <Button x:Name="ListBoxSCity"  Height="17" Content="{Binding Genre}" FontSize="11" Click="ListBoxSGenre_Click"/>
         <Button x:Name="ListBoxSGenre" Height="17" Content="{Binding Country}" FontSize="11" Click="ListBoxSCountry_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: This worked almost perfect. The only thing is that even thought they are docked Right and left now, they leave a huge white space in the right.

Comment: Use `DockPanel.Dock="Fill"` it one of them, as it will use all the available space left. Behare of the `HorizontalAlignment` in this case

Comment: That worked perfect. Thank you. I decided thought not to follow StackPanel. I Did it like this : 1st Button : DockPanel.Dock="Right" 2nd Button : DockPanel.Dock="Right" 3nd Button : HorizontalAlignment="Right". And all items in the DockPanel.

Comment: Only careful about the order of the buttons

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`Grid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx), `DockPanel` is not a good control. Also `Grids` have [size-sharing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.definitionbase.sharedsizegroup.aspx), which is often useful for items controls.